# Postgres transparent tiering of older data to second server

Tags: postgresql

Assume we have a large database - say 10 terabytes.  One table, which could be partitioned by time. So it has years of data, but only recent data needs to be queried performantly.   I'd like to host old data, on a less powerful machine, with lots of storage.  But for that to be transparent to the client.

With Postgres, is it possible to:

- partition the table declaratively, by month (say)
- have the current month's partition as defined as on the powerful server.  The clients always query this server.
- use the foreign data wrapper (on an inherited table?) to set the older months to be served by the less powerful machine
- use streaming replication to keep the less powerful machine up to date. It technically has all the data, but the partition setup means that recent data is not served by it.

If not, is this scenario typically covered with other Postgres features?

Comment: All of that is currently supported by Postgres. But streaming replication replicates the entire "cluster" (aka "data directory" or "instance"). You can't use it to selectively replicate data. But replication **duplicates** the data, so it would still be on main server.

Comment: thanks, so that is the key issue - not having to provision storage for the entire dataset on the powerful servers.